# Variable classname using namespaces in php

Tags: php, namespaces

I want to use a variable class name in PHP with a prefixed namespace.

Three variants I have tried produce expectation of an identifier error after the last backslash.

```
(\api\controllers\(new $class()))->{$method}($this->id);

((new \api\controllers\$class()))->{$method}($this->id);

((new \api\controllers\{$class()}))->{$method}($this->id));
```

How do I make this work?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? It seems like you might be jumping through hoops that you could simply walk around instead...

Comment: If this is a requirement for your application, you should probably rethink the structure of your application.

Comment: I want to pick up the class name in the desired namespace matching other file name in another namespace.  I have `use` command available but I am trying to see if this will work.   Please clarify the drawbacks to this approach.   Since I use an autoloader I have switched order of autloaded directories which eliminates the class name addressing in this fashion need for this in the present script.

Comment: @GregSchmidt, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55680983/php-api-app-simplifying-directory-structure-controller-model-for-sample-app for context to my application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
$full_class_name = '\api\controllers\' . $class;
$controller = new $full_class_name();
$controller->{$method}($this->id);
```

It can probably be shortened somewhat, but doing that here would perhaps make the answer more obscure and less helpful.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense, I was overlooking the fact that my $class variable was being added to the end of a literal namespace path.  That's why it didn't work.